# How to display texts in the middle of screen with Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter. I want to display two text with Column in middle of the screen.

But when I tried `Center`, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeTYn.jpg). It displays texts in top of the screen. Why this happens?

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello world"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello"
            ),
            Text(
              "World"
            )
          ],
        )
        )
      );
  }
}
```

Also, when I use `Container` instead of `Column`, it displays in center of screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJohB.jpg).

What's the problem

I'm using Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Specify a `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` property on the `Column` to center the children. In your code, the `Column` widget is actually centered vertically and horizontally but the `Column` widget extends to the full height and by default the alignment is `MainAxisAlignment.start` which makes the children start from the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello world"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,//main axis the vertical axis in a column so this positions the children at the center of the vertical axis
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,//the horizontal axis of a column, again we position the children's at the center of the horizontal axis
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello"
            ),
            Text(
              "World"
            )
          ],
        )
        )
      );
  }
}
```

This should work
What you were missing is `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisiAlignment`
Remember in `Column()`, `mainAxisAlignment` in the vertical axis and `crossAxisiAlignment` is the horizontal axis and this is opposite in a `Row()`

Comment: What should I do if I want to change `crossAxisiAlignment` to left? Of course I tried `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.left`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I find it out; I have to use `start` and `end` instead of `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello"
            ),
            Text(
              "World"
            )
          ],
        )
```